# Express-session creates new session every request

Tags: node.js, express, session, express-session

I put my node express server into production. In development, express-session worked fine (it stored session into cookies with **MemoryStore**). But now it creates a new session ID into **MongoStore** every time I refresh or make a request. Also, it doesn't create a cookie in the browser anymore (idk if it's a good or a bad thing)

Most StackOverflow queries on this topic tell me to do things that I've already done so no help there

Here is my express and session setup:

```
const app = express()

const apiPort = process.env.PORT || process.env.API_PORT
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: process.env.ORIGIN_URL}))

mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error(err);
    console.log('MongoDB connection error. Please make sure MongoDB is running.');
    process.exit();
});

const sessionMiddleware = session({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    // secure: true,
    cookie: {
        sameSite: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30
    },
    store: MongoStore.create({
        mongoUrl: process.env.MONGODB_URI
    })
})

app.use(sessionMiddleware);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/auth/login', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
      if (err) { return next(err); }
      if (info) {
          return res.status(401).json({error: info.msg})
      }
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        return res.status(200).send(user);
      });
    })(req, res, next);
});

app.get('/auth/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.logout()
    res.sendStatus(200)
});

app.get('/checkToken', authCheck, (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send({accountType: res.accountType});
})
```

Additional info that might be handy for this problem: the front-end is on a separate domain, the aforementioned server is on Heroku, and the DB is in MongoDB cloud.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out all I was missing was `app.set('trust proxy', 1)` in my setup and `sameSite: 'none'` in `cookie: {}` in session middleware.