# Nodejs/Express API Axios/Reactjs UI on separate Azure Web Apps over HTTPS - Session keeps changing

Tags: express, session, https, axios, cors

**Problem: Sessionid changes with every API call so session data is not saved**

I have an  issue with the Sessionid changing on every API call probably the result of a simple error.
When using localhost and HTTP the Sessionid is stable and the cookie outputs correctly.
Moving to Azure web apps the sessionid changes on each API call.
The cookie tab is missing on chrome network tab - but I think this is expected with secure settings.
I believe my CORS setup is correct and the APIs can be called without error.

**API**

Api running nodejs and express on a standard linux web app
No setting alterations on standard webapp apart from logging settings for application output.

**UI - react ui with Vite**

Running on separate linux standard web app
Environment variables in the build YAML, because VITE needs these at build time.
Axios  - is used for the APIs
OAuth0 - is used for authentication
Standard azure web app domain is used - so azure provided certificates - no custom domains

**Known**

The SessionId and cookie work find in localhost and from postman calls.

**So the differences are**

- HTTPS rather than HTTP
- Separate Azure web apps for UI and Server rather than localhost
- CORS setup needed to manage cross domain issues
- I am using the same browser for the HTTP and HTTPS versions so I do not think it is a browser issue

**Azure Server configuration**

```
    ...
    CLIENT_ORIGIN_URL - `https://t*****5.azurewebsites.net`
    NODE_ENV - `azure`
    ...
```

**Server code**

Set up the cookie parser

```
    ...
    const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    ....
    app.use(cookieParser()); 
    ....
```

Session - In memory session for now

```
    ...
    const sessionStore = new session.MemoryStore();
    ...
```

The secret is in a .env for localhost and in keyvault for azure web app, this is logged so I know it is correct

**Session creation**

```
    ...
    domain = process.env.CLIENT_ORIGIN_URL; // Logged so I know this is correct
    ...
      const sessionMiddleware = session({
        genid: (req) => {
            return uuid();
        },
        store: sessionStore,
        name: 'session',
        secret: sessionSecret, // logged so I know this is correct
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: {
            domain: domain,
            path: '/',
            maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 1 day
            httpOnly: (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'azure') ? true : false, 
            secure:  (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'azure') ? true : false, 
            sameSite: (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'azure') ? 'None' : 'Lax'
        }
    });
    ...
    app.use(sessionMiddleware);
    ...
    //Associate with app 
    ...
       app.use(cors({
        credentials: true,
        origin: domain // logged so I know this is correct
    }));
    ...
```

**React UI**

```
    //UI build - yaml variables
    ...
    VITE_APP_AUTH0_AUDIENCE: https://T*****20.azurewebsites.net
    ...
```

```
    //Axios setup - I've tried without axios as well
    ...
    const audienceUri = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_AUTH0_AUDIENCE;

    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;    // tried with and without this
    const BASE_URL = `${audienceUri}/api/v1`; // Replace with your API URL 

    //audienceUri logged and correct
    const defaultConfig = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    };

    const instance = axios.create({
       withCredentials: true, // tried moving this to the config as well
       baseURL: BASE_URL, // Logged so I know this is correct
    });
```

Example - all APIs  follow this pattern

```
    // Generic function to make GET requests
    export const get = async (resource, config) => {
        const response = await instance.get(resource, { ...defaultConfig, ...config });
        return response;
    };

     // Get call - calls the base definition.
     // Config at this point is the Bearer token
     import * as Api from './Api';

     export const getAll = (config) => Api.get('users', config);
```

**This server method is called several times**

```
    app.get("/api/v1/users", async function (req, res) {
        try {
           console.log("T*****: Session ID - users: ", req.sessionID, req.cookies);
           res.status(200).json({
               status: "success",
               data: {
                   users: ["Jim", "Sam", "Bob"],
               }
           })
        } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

**Problem**

Azure instances - sessionid constantly changes
There is no other code to handle cors, cookies or sessions apart from that given above.

**Example logs from Azure server instance**

- 2023-11-21T17:35:17.846927632Z T*****: Session ID - users:  5f25e7b7-516d-441f-b6e1-305057449b0d [Object: null prototype] {}
- 2023-11-21T17:35:27.277838067Z T*****: Session ID - users:  54726557-1c6a-4e84-94f1-add1c04bf97e [Object: null prototype] {}
- 2023-11-21T17:35:33.361667671Z T*****: Session ID - users:  e01b12a2-dbe1-446d-b2b5-1ec2bcd6ef3f [Object: null prototype] {}

The server url follows this format
http://T*****20.azurewebsites.net/api/v1/users

Any pointers to help me work this out would be amazing. thank you

I have tried on postman and localhost
I have tried removing Axios
I have tried various combinations to setup cors but I think what I have is standard

Comment: I added this 
    app.set('trust proxy', 1)


From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66691130/express-session-creates-new-session-every-request

As far as I am aware there are no proxy servers involved so confused - Now if works - don't understand why yet.......